# Rigorous proof that the powers of a number h in interval (0,1) are smaller as the exponent is larger (exponent being natural)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I wonder how to prove this, and I would like to see the different ways to do it. My approach was by defining the sequence a_n:=h^n where n is natural and h is a fixed value inside the interval (0,1). Then, what I wanted to prove is that the sequence is decreasing ie: a_n+1<= a_n for all n. From here one could say that this happens iff an<= a_n-1 since h is a nonzero by assumption and so for until reaching that it all holds iff a_2<= a_1 which is that h^2 < h and that holds iff h<1 which is true indeed. I also wanted to verify that this proof is valid as well. Thanks

Comment: do you mean $h^n\le e^h$, for $h\in(0,1)$?

Comment: No, I mean that h^n+1 <= h^n

Comment: Since $h$ is positive , $h^n$ is positive for every non-negative integer $n$ , hence the inequatlity $h<1$ , multiplied with $h^n$ , gives $h^{n+1}<h^n$ , hence the sequence strictly decreases with increasing $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $h\in (0,1)$ and $n$ a natural number. Then
$$
h^{n+1} - h^n = h^n(h-1) <0
$$
as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Take $h=\dfrac{1}{1+A}$ for an $A>0$, and think and settle on
$(1+A)^n<(1+A)^{n+1}$.

Then
$$\dfrac{1}{(1+A)^{n+1}}<\dfrac{1}{(1+A)^n}.$$